# Is there any way to use jQTouch with URL bar?

Tags: jquery, redirect, url-rewriting, jqtouch

I'm developing mobile website with jQTouch.

Let's pick official demo site for example. When we go to  [here](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home), we see the main screen. Navigate to AJAX -> Get Example. We see our location bar changed to `/#get`. But, if we'll copy that address (`http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#get`) and paste it into the browser, jQTouch will redirect us to `#home` page.

Is there any way to prevent such redirection and just use the location bar normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, part of the magic of jqTouch is it's use of address bar and location.hash to allow moving "pages" but really only moving a div in and out of the main viewing window.